# Let a LTI system be causal and stable with the transfer function being... show that

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, complex, proof, cepstral-analysis

if the system is an  IIR LTI causal and stable one, and the transfer function is

\[H(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h[n]z{^{n}}= \frac{G}{1 -\sum_{k=1}^{p}a_kz{^{-k}}}\]


show that the cepstrum of this system can be calculated by the following equation
\[\hat{h}[n]= a_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left ( \frac{k}{n} \right )\hat{h}[k]a_{n-k}, n\geq 1\]
where  
\[\hat{h}[n]=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}log[H(e{^{j\omega}})]e{^{j\omega n}} d\omega\] 
is the complex cepstrum.
Im basically skipping a lot of parts in defining cepstrum but basically 
\[\hat{H}(z)= log[H(z)] \] 


Any Ideas what should I look into for answering this question?

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: So is asking help with homework off the line? or just generally against the rules?

Comment: asking for help with homework is totally OK, but you need to explain and show what you've tried so far, where that fails, and ask a specific question of your own that helps you find an answer yourself. Your question seems to just repeat the question *you* are supposed to answer!

Comment: thanks a ton for replying but I really don't know where I should ask with this one so I thought of asking for hints or some guidance.

Comment: @poggers100 Even if you don't have any idea how to start, letting us know what you would do or what theory you would apply would get the StackExchange machine going!

Comment: How about just adding in the _definition_ of cepstrum such as "I know that the cepstrum $\hat{h}[n]$ of an LTI filter with pulse response $h[n]$ is defined as .....  but I don't know how to get from $h[n]$ to $\hat{h}[n]$."